# Bad return type in lambda expression String cannot be converted to Object

Tags: java, lambda, mapping, java-stream, collectors

I need to concat data if duplicates will occur. But can't to do it.

Is it possible to convert String to Object in that case or join that data by another expression?

I have a problem there: `(a, b) -> a + ", " + b` as
*Bad return type in lambda expression String cannot be converted to Subject*

```
Map<Student, Subject> result = markList
           .stream()
           .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                  Mark::getStudent,
                  Mark::getSubject,
               (a, b) -> a + ", " + b));

result.forEach((student, subject) -> 
         System.out.printf("%s %s : %s ", student.getFirstName(), 
                   student.getLastName(), subject.getName()));
```

Here is markList:

```
List<Mark> markList = new ArrayList<>();
markList.add(new Mark(student_1, subject_1, 1));
markList.add(new Mark(student_1, subject_2, 2));
markList.add(new Mark(student_2, subject_1, 1));
```

And expect to get **joined Subject data** in case duplicates would found

**Expected Output:**

*[ `student_1` with `subject_1`, `subject_2` and
`student_2` with `subject_1` ]:*

`John McDonald: Mathematics, Astronomy`

`Kira Wild: Mathematics`

=====================================================

**But**
this code works without duplicates as: `(a, b) -> a`

*Output:*

`John McDonald: Mathematics`

`Kira Wild: Mathematics`

Comment: what do you want? can you explain with small example?

Comment: Also, Please post `Mark`, `Student` and `Subject` classes.

Comment: Define *duplicates* and an example would be actually very useful here to see what is desired.

Comment: Sorry, Question were been edited

Comment: @31113 please consider adding some sample data and what you expect as a result, that way your question will be much clearer and people would be more willing to provide you with a solution.

Comment: @31113 people would also like to know what it means "to join subject data"

Comment: @Aomine thank you, did it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First things first, `(a, b) -> a + ", " + b)` will not compile simply because the returned value must be a `Subject` rather than a `String`, I believe you have eventually figured this out given your latest edit states the code is now working without duplicates when using the `(a, b) -> a` merge function.

The reason why you're not getting the expected result given your latest update is that you're using the merge function `(a, b) -> a` meaning "if two given Subjects have the same Student then keep the first student and discard the second".

Instead what you want to do is somehow maintain both students so in essence, you'll have a `Map<Student, List<Subject>>`.

This can be done as:

```
Map<Student, List<Subject>> result = markList
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                        Mark::getStudent,
                        v -> new ArrayList<>(singletonList(v.getSubject())),
                        (a, b) -> {a.addAll(b); return a;}));
```

Actually this is better done via `groupingBy` with a `mapping` as downstream collector:

```
Map<Student, List<Subject>> resultSet = markList.stream()
                .collect(groupingBy(Mark::getStudent,
                        mapping(Mark::getSubject, toList())));
```

and finally you can test the results with:

```
resultSet.forEach((student, subjects) ->
                System.out.printf("%s %s : %s ", student.getFirstName(), student.getLastName(), 
                        subjects.stream().map(Subject::getName).collect(joining(", "))));
```